# Using LINQ to get information from two tables, with a join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a linq statement to populate two labels. The thing is, this information comes from two tables. I Have a join to join the two tables, except i cant get my Terms and Conditions from my Campaign table. Its only picking up the RedemptionLog table columns. Anyone to help with this?

```
MSCDatabaseDataContext MSCDB = new MSCDatabaseDataContext();
            var q = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_RedemptionLogs 
                    join d in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns on row.CampaignId equals d.CampaignId
                    orderby row.VoucherCode descending
                    select row;

            var SeshVoucherDisplay = q.First();

            lblCode.Text = SeshVoucherDisplay.VoucherCode;
            lblTerms.Text = SeshVoucherDisplay
```

For the SeshVoucherDisplay variable, it only picks up from the RedemptionLogs table, yet i did a join? Any help?

Comment: Are you want to both table data in SeshVoucherDisplay ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
var SupJoin = from row in MSCDB.Tbl_RedemptionLogs
              join d in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns on row.CampaignId equals d.CampaignId
              orderby row.VoucherCode descending
              select new { Id = row.ID, SupplierName = row.SupplierName, 
               CustomerName = d.CompanyName };
```

The column names are just for example purpose. Put your own there. And thereafter, you can apply `First` on it and use that particular variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, i only started development this year. This is my first project. Could you try help me with the names of the columns, related to my table? I have tried mixing and matching, but getting errors. Sorry to hassle you.

Comment: Fine. Update your question and reveal the necessary tables and columns that you want in the LINQ query.

Comment: Hey thanks, i figured it out. Its just not pulling the correct information, but im sure ill figure it out. I appreciate your help man, got me one step closer.

Comment: Glad that it helped brother.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by writing `select row` you asked LINQ to give back to you only `row`.

If you want both elements, you need to ask for both of them, e.g. by writing `select new { row, d }`.

In this example

```
var foo =
    new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "a" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "b" },
        new { Id = 3, Name = "c" }
    };

var bar =
    new []
    {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "d" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "e" },
        new { Id = 3, Name = "f" }
    };

var baz =
    from a in foo
    join b in bar on a.Id equals b.Id
    select new { a, b };

var qux =
    from a in foo
    join b in bar on a.Id equals b.Id
    select new { a, b };
```

In `baz` you'll find only a list of `foo`s, in `qux` you'll find a list of both `foo`s and their `bar`.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot dude. But i have ONE more question haha, thanks for your help so far. But how would i get the last entry in the database? From my RedemptionLogs table. I Would assume, that stating var SeshVoucher = q.First(); after stating OrderBy Descending on Voucher Code, because that is the last entry, is it not? It might be my terms and conditions not matching up to the redemptions log table. Im not sure, do you think you could help?

Comment: If `MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns` contains more than one entry for a given `MSCDB.Tbl_RedemptionLogs` entry (and that's possible, what you wrote is a [one-to-many join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) you need to sort for `MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns` too.

Comment: Thanks man i got it. since you couldnt see my information, it made your solution a lot harder to pin point. All i had to do was order by descending on the Redemption id, as that is the primary key. (My Voucher codes are hashed, so it orders them by biggest to smallest, not when they were entered.) But thanks a lot dude, you helped me solve this. I AM DONE MY FIRST PROJECT :D :D :D Thanks! @Albireo

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = (from row in MSCDB.Tbl_RedemptionLogs
                                 join d in MSCDB.Tbl_Campaigns on row.CampaignId equals d.CampaignId)
                                 orderby row.VoucherCode descending
                                 select new
                                 {
                                    columnname = row.columnname
                                 });
```

Comment: Thanks dude, youre just a second too late . I got it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

When writing `select row` you relate to the row you defined in `from row in MSCDB.Tbl_RedemptionLogs`.

However if you want the data from both tables you have to write something similar to this:

```
select new { 
    // the properties of row
    Redemption = row.redemption, 
    // the properties of d
    Campaign = d.CampaignID // alternativly use may also use row.CampaignID, but I wanted to show you may acces all the members from d also 
}
```

Comment: What is prop1 and what is Prop2?

Comment: Some dummy-properties from `row` and from `d` as I don´t know which properties those objects provide.